# Why does meshgrid order output dimensions differently than the order provided with input?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand how meshgrid indexes dimensions of the outputs with respect to the inputs. I've noticed it will always transpose the first two dimensions. For example, when providing x with length 7 and y with length 6 it will return the output arrays as a 6x7 array instead of a 7x6 one.

This is clearly by design so I'm trying to understand the why/logic so I can use it as intended. Can someone shine a light on this? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

#specify input dimensions of different lengths to aid in identifying which output index a dimension belongs to
x = np.linspace(0,60,7)
y = np.linspace(0,50,6)
z = np.linspace(0,40,5)
i = np.linspace(0,30,4)
j = np.linspace(0,20,3)

#2D mesh grid, output dimensions transposed from input
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print(xx.shape)
print(yy.shape)

#3D mesh grid, first two output dimensions transposed from input
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
print(xx.shape)
print(yy.shape)
print(zz.shape)

#4D meshgrid, first two output dimensions transposed from input, rest are in input order
xx, yy, zz, ii = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,i)
print(xx.shape)
print(yy.shape)
print(zz.shape)
print(ii.shape)

#5D meshgrid, first two output dimensions transposed from input, rest are in input order
xx, yy, zz, ii, jj = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,i,j)
print(xx.shape)
print(yy.shape)
print(zz.shape)
print(ii.shape)
print(jj.shape)
```

Comment: You can control the order - read the docs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to do this with the 'indexing' option set to 'ij. This feature was added in numpy version 1.7.0.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

```
import numpy as np

#specify input dimensions of different lengths to aid in identifying which index dimension belongs to in output
x = np.linspace(0,60,7)
y = np.linspace(0,50,6)
z = np.linspace(0,40,5)
i = np.linspace(0,30,4)
j = np.linspace(0,20,3)

#2D mesh grid, output dimensions transposed from input
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')
print(xx.shape)
print(yy.shape)

#3D mesh grid, first two output dimensions transposed from input
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,indexing='ij')
print(xx.shape)
print(yy.shape)
print(zz.shape)

#4D meshgrid, first two output dimensions transposed from input, rest are in input order
xx, yy, zz, ii = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,i,indexing='ij')
print(xx.shape)
print(yy.shape)
print(zz.shape)
print(ii.shape)

#5D meshgrid, first two output dimensions transposed from input, rest are in input order
xx, yy, zz, ii, jj = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,i,j,indexing='ij')
print(xx.shape)
print(yy.shape)
print(zz.shape)
print(ii.shape)
print(jj.shape)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the difference between axis coordinates and matrix coordinates. When you think of a set of axes in a reference frame, it makes sense to first mention x and only then y. For example, we have all been taught y = f(x). However, in terms of matrices, we know we need to index by rows first: (0, 1) is the first element of the second column. Now if you try to represent a matrix on a graph, there is a problem, because the x axis will correspond to the columns and y axis to the rows: there is a mismatch. As a result, if you were to obtain a (7, 6) array and simply paste it on the graph, then the coordinates would not match because columns values would be y coordinates. This is, I believe, why a transpose operation is needed, to be consistent between the matrix representation and the axes coordinates.

Comment: That explains the insight and the "why" I was looking for. Thanks.
When going beyond two dimensions I suppose thinking in terms of axes no longer works because we can't visualize it, which is why additional dimensions (3rd, 4th, etc.) revert to being ordered according to their matrix index?

Comment: I would just say that adding further dimensions is not a problem because they do not produce any mismatch. But indeed, the visual example stops working when you introduce a fourth dimension.